# Testing laravel routes identify method type

Tags: laravel, routes, phpunit

How can I get about a Laravel route if the request is a get or post?

I try to test my laravel routes with the following

```
public function testRoutes()
    {
        $app = app();
        $routes = $app->routes->getRoutes();


        /**
         * Test if mynamespace routes are redirected to login page if is not the login page
         */
        echo  PHP_EOL;

        foreach ($routes as $route) {

            if(strpos($route->getName(),'mynamespace::' ) !== false ) {

                $url = $route->uri;

                //$appURL = env('APP_URL') .'/';

                $response = $this->get($url);

                if((int)$response->status() !== 200 ){
                    echo   $url . ' (FAILED) did not return 200. The response is ' . $response->status();
                    $this->assertTrue(false);
                } else {
                    echo  $url . ' (success ?)';
                    $this->assertTrue(true);
                }
                echo  PHP_EOL;

            }
        }
    }
```

but I would like exclude post requests for the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we can see the `Route` class has a property `$methods`.

Your solution would look something like:

```
if (in_array('POST', $route->methods)) continue;
```

It may be interesting for you to look into the testing provided by Laravel itself. A simple way of testing response testing and much more!

[Laravel testing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/testing).